# Referencing one computed column from another

Tags: sas, calculated-columns, enterprise-guide

I'm using SAS Enterprise Guide 7.1 and i'm having a problem with something that seems fairly basic. I'll simplify the problem but fundamentally I have one computed column (Computed_column1) that uses a CASE/WHEN statement e.g.

```
CASE
WHEN x > y THEN "TRUE"
ELSE "FALSE"
END
```

I'd like to reference the first computed column in a second computed column (Computed_column2) but instead of referring to the computed column name the advanced expression tab in the query builder pulls through all of the contents from the first computed column. Therefore if i need to change the first column i'll have to change the second one also.

So my second computed column looks something like this:

```
CASE
WHEN (CASE WHEN x > y THEN "TRUE" ELSE "FALSE" END) > z THEN "TRUE"
ELSE "FALSE"
END
```

When i'd like it to be some type of dynamic reference like:

```
CASE
WHEN Computed_column1 > z THEN "TRUE"
ELSE "FALSE"
END
```

This way if the first computed column changes the second will also. Is this not possible?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: If you're using the query builder you're stuck with the code it generates, but I assume if you fix it one place in the query builder it will also fix elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

You can read more about calculated variables [here](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi29/268-29.pdf) (paragraph name "THE CALCULATED OPTION ON THE SELECT"). In your case you should write:

```
CASE
WHEN CALCULATED Computed_column1 > z THEN "TRUE"
ELSE "FALSE"
END
```

Answer (score 3):

This works almost as exactly as you've imagined it. Just use `calculated` rather than `computed`.